# Are the solid supports used in oligonucleotide synthesis reusable?

Tags: dna-rna

So in solid-support oligonucleotide synthesis, the protected nucleotides are attached at either the 3' or 5' end to a linker, which is then itself attached to a a solid support. After synthesis, the linker and oligonucleotide are cleaved from the solid support and each other. Deprotection and purification occur.

What I don't understand, is if I'm using a nucleosidic support, is the support reusable? I mean, once I cleave the linker and oligonucleotide from the support, presumably the support is no longer nucleosidic. But if I can just reuse the support and attach my own different linker and nucleoside to it, then what exactly is the advantage of universal supports?

This may be a stupid question, but I cannot for the life of me find the answer to it and I struggle to answer it intuitively myself because I have no background in biochemistry or even chemistry in general. I do not doubt I am totally misunderstanding something here.

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot reuse a solid support.
See, the solid support is usually a polymer, as for instance a silica based resin, chemically functionalized with something that will be attached to this resin, but that will also be able to react with the oligonucleotide's first monomer (last, actually since the synthesis is 3' to 5'), and have this monomer attached to it at the end of the 4 steps synthetic cycle. In the next cycle another monomer will attach to the already attached monomer and that will repeat as many times as the number of nucleotides in the desired oligo.

Traditionally, solid supports were sold with the first synthetic monomer already attached to it. So when you configured the synthesis you would have to analyze what was the last nucleotide in the oligo sequence, and use the solid support with that specific nt to initiate the synthesis from the second nt.

Latter, they developed universal supports, which would not have any nucleotides already attached, meaning you could just use the same resin to synthesize any oligos, regardless of the sequence, and of course, now you would start the synthesis by the last nt, and not by the second last (remember, the synthesis starts by the last nt, the last nt in the oligo sequence is the first to be attached, and the first nt in the sequence is attached in the last cycle).

After the synthesis you have to release the oligo from the solid support by cleaving the linker. To use the same support again, you would have to chemically attach a new linker, but only after really assuring that absolutely no trace of the oligo you synthesized in it before were left. That would be so laborious that is definitely not worthy.

To be sure you are synthesizing perfectly free from cross contamination oligos, use always fresh new solid supports, including the inert frits (if you are using a resin).

Comment: This is helpful, but you open up by stating it can't when you conclude later that *it shouldn't* be reused, or at least that it would be time consuming and laborious to do so (*probably* not worth the time and money).

Comment: Yes, you are right, it is possible, but it is not because it is possible, that you can do it. In practical terms when you are in the oligo synthesis universe you just CANNOT reuse a solid support. Not only because it is not worthy, but mainly due to quality issues - really serious quality issues. So, it is feasible, but it is not allowed, you just can't.